# solving of zero indexing issue in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-indexing

suppose that we have  some vector  y in matlab and let us suppose that there is  such linear relationship between values of y
[image]

of course first   vector can be easily implemented by

y(L:N-1), but related to matrix, we dont have index y[0] in matlab, so how can i solve this issue? there is another picture

[image]

should i use index y[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0col.png) and instead of index y(l-1),start from y(l)?

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is zero-based, while Matlab is one-based in terms of array indexing. Therefore, the best solution is to add 1 every index in the equation: the vector on the left hand side runs from L+1:N, instead of L:N-1, and the elements in the matrix from 1 to L or N-L (whichever is larger), instead of 0 to L-1 or N-L-1.